# tableviewdeleterows crashing app even though data was updated

Tags: swift, xcode

I currently have this block of code that should delete a table row.

```
extension HomeController: SwipeTableViewCellDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
    guard orientation == .right else { return nil }
    print("in delete")
    let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { [self] action, indexPath in
        print("currently deleting")
        userHabitData.remove(at: indexPath.section)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }

    // customize the action appearance
    deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete")

    return [deleteAction]
}
```

I made sure to change my data source before deleting the row with

```
userHabitData.remove(at: indexPath.section)
```

However the code still throws this error

> Thread 1: "Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)."

Here is my complete view controller

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Habit Tracker
//
//  Created by Alan Weng on 11/24/20.
//

import UIKit
import SwipeCellKit

class tableViewCell: SwipeTableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var habitName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var habitCount: UILabel!
    
    
    var habit: Habit? {
        didSet {
            self.updateUI()
        }
    }
    
    func updateUI() {
        print("being run")
        habitName?.text = habit?.title
        habitCount?.text = habit?.detail
//        progressLabel?.observedProgress = habit?.progress
    }
    
}

class HomeController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var deno_label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    let impactFeedbackgenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
    @IBOutlet weak var deno_img: UIImageView!
    var UserHabitDict: [String:String] = [:]
    var userHabitData = [HabitDict]()
    var userHabitName: String?
    var userHabitCount: String?
    let cellReuseID = "habitName"
    let cellSpacingHeight: CGFloat = 15
    let customRed = UIColor().customRed()
    let customBlue = UIColor().customBlue()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    @IBAction func createNewGoal(_ sender: Any) {
        let goalVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: cellReuseID) as! CreateGoalController
        impactFeedbackgenerator.prepare()
        impactFeedbackgenerator.impactOccurred()
        goalVC.habitDelegate = self
        present(goalVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    // Think of how ios settings have different sections w diff spacings
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return UserHabitDict.count
    }
    
    // Adjusts cell spacing between habits
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return cellSpacingHeight
    }
    
    // Adjust row height
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 75
    }
    
    // Allows the table to keep expanding based on how many habits are in the array
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    // Make the background color show through
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return headerView
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if habitIsEmpty() {
            deno_img.alpha = 0.0
            deno_label.alpha = 0.0
        }
        print("making habit")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseID) as! tableViewCell
        let dictKey = userHabitData[indexPath.section].getName()
        let dictValue = userHabitData[indexPath.section].getCount()
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.backgroundColor = customBlue
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.habit = Habit(title: dictKey, detail: dictValue)
        print(userHabitData)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsOptionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> SwipeOptions {
        var options = SwipeOptions()
        options.expansionStyle = .destructive
        options.transitionStyle = .border
        return options
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // note that indexPath.section is used rather than indexPath.row
//        print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.section).")
//        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseID) as! tableViewCell
//      cell.habit?.updateDetail()
//      tableView.reloadData()
//        let dictKey = userHabitData[indexPath.section].getName()
//        var dictValue = userHabitData[indexPath.section].getCount()
//        print("over here")
//        dictValue = String(Int(dictValue)! - 1)
//        print(dictValue)
//        cell.habit = Habit(title: dictKey, detail: dictValue)
//        tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    
    func allowMultipleLines(tableViewCell: UITableViewCell) {
        tableViewCell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    }
    
    func habitIsEmpty() -> Bool {
        if userHabitData.isEmpty {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
    
}

extension HomeController: CreateGoalDelegate {
    func didTapSave(name: String, count: String) {
        userHabitName = name
        userHabitCount = count
        UserHabitDict[name] = count
        userHabitData.append(HabitDict(habitName: name, habitCount: count))
//      tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: userHabitData.count, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
        tableView.reloadData()
        print("in reload data")
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    func customRed() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 0.607, green: 0.160, blue: 0.282, alpha: 1.00)
    }
    func customBlue() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 0.509, green: 0.701, blue: 0.964, alpha: 1.00)
    }
}

struct HabitDict {
    let habitName: String
    let habitCount: String
    
    func getName() -> String {
        return habitName
    }
    
    func getCount() -> String {
        return habitCount
    }
}

extension HomeController: SwipeTableViewCellDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
        guard orientation == .right else { return nil }
        print("in delete")
        let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { [self] action, indexPath in
            print("currently deleting")
            userHabitData.remove(at: indexPath.section)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }

        // customize the action appearance
        deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete")

        return [deleteAction]
    }
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Try [`deleteSections(_:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614922-deletesections) instead of `deleteRows`

Comment: I actually tried doing that from the beginning but it still throws the same error

Comment: Can you try `self.userHabitData.remove(at: indexPath.section)`?

Comment: its still giving me the same result, I did some debugging and saw that the array count after the remove was indeed 0 while the row count was 1 before I deleted the row. I believe this is supposed to be right output which confuses me even more

Comment: The following line doesn't make sense.  userHabitData.remove(at: indexPath.section)

Comment: Also, the following lines don't make sense.  let dictKey = userHabitData[indexPath.section].getName();let dictValue = userHabitData[indexPath.section].getCount()

Comment: userHabitData is an array of dictionaries. I had to make a custom one since dictionaries dont retain the order that you put them in

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your data source is inconsistent.

In the `delete` method the data source array is `userHabitData` however in `numberOfSections` you are using `UserHabitDict` which is not being updated in the delete action.

Replace `numberOfSections` with

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return userHabitData.count
}
```

and then delete the **section** (including the row)

```
let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { [self] action, indexPath in
    print("currently deleting")
    userHabitData.remove(at: indexPath.section)
    tableView.deleteSections([indexPath.section], with: .fade)
}
```

And please remove the `getName` and `getCount` functions in the struct. They are redundant. Use the name and count members directly. And you could remove also the redundant information *Habit* from the names

Comment: thanks so much for your response! I applied the changes but unfortunately it still gives me the same error message. I'm also wondering why you have "at" inside of tableView.deleteSections as xcode gives me an error "Extraneous argument label 'at:' in call" not sure if im missing something here

Comment: My bad, remove `at:`. If the data source array is consistent the code is supposed to work.

Comment: for some reason my code works fine without the use of swipecellkit, I used UITableViewCell.EditingStyle and it works fine!